# Unable to import json objects from json file in DJANGO

Tags: python, json, django

I am unable to create json objects from json file in Django. Here is the code.
I have a file called out.json with json objects in it. I want to send those objects as response. I am getting an error saying

**FileNotFoundError at /projectboard/random
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out.json'**

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
import sys, os
import json  
from django.http import JsonResponse
from tempfile import *

import subprocess


# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse

def random(request):
    os.system('python pypy.py')

    with open('out.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
        print(data)

    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
      url(r'^random$', views.random, name='random'),
      url(r'^view/(?P<id_remedio>\w+)/$', views.view, name='view'),
      url(r'^view/$', views.view, name='view')
]
```

Comment: Where is `out.json` stored?

Comment: out.json is stored in the same directory, i.e Projectboard

Comment: Seem like it is not able to find the `out.json` . Try by giving the absolute path or relative path corresponding to views.py of `out.json`

Comment: Move out.json to this directory `/projectboard/random` or get an absolute path to the file and pass it here 
`with open(absolute_path) as json_data:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

out.json file should be at the same directory with manage.py file

```
foo/
    manage.py
    foo/
       __init__.py
       settings.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py

    out.json
```

Answer (score 1):

Move out.json to directory
`/projectboard/out.json`

`out.json` must be in the same directory as `views.py`, or as the py file calling `open(file)`. If you're using Linux or OS X, navigate to the `/projectboard` folder and type `ls` to list the files to double check `out.json` is located in the correct path. Otherwise use `dir` on a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure to include a full path to the file. Unless your `out.json` is in the **same folder** as the file trying to open it, you will get that error.

Better yet, if you have objects in a file as above for several of your apps, or just to clean your project clean, I would include a /fixtures/ folder in your app, and drop all .json files in there. You then have an easy way to retrieve the root of these files (can include it in your `settings.py` file) -- something like:

```
FIXTURES_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/fixtures/'
```

You can then just use

```
from django.conf import settings
...
json_path = settings.FIXTURES_ROOT + <YOUR_JSON_FILENAME>
```

throughout your project